# While making my first bot this error came "client = discord.client() TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
import discord

client = discord.client()

client.run('token')
```

This is my first bot code, I am getting the error

```
  client = discord.client()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Please help me with what am I missing? I am trying to bring my Discord bot online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the correct case.
It should be `discord.Client()` with an upper case 'C'

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

client.run(token)
```